# Convex combination inequality

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, convex-analysis

I have been doing some work which resulted in the following inequality, which I believe to be true, but am unsure how to prove. Let $\lambda_i, \mu_i \geq 0$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i=1$. Is it true that
$$\sum_{i \neq j}\lambda_i\lambda_j \leq  2\sum_{i \neq j}\mu_i\lambda_j \;?$$

Comment: What have you tried? How is this motivated by convex analysis?

Comment: Can you show your working? I think this is a somewhat immediate deduction, so I'd like to see where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Start with WTS

$$ \frac{ (\sum \lambda_i )^2 - \sum \lambda_i ^2 } { 2 } \leq ( \sum \lambda_i ) (\sum \mu_j) - \sum \lambda_i\mu_i. $$

Replace several terms by 1, then simplify again.

> WTS: $ 1 - \sum \lambda_i ^2  \leq 2  - 2 \sum \lambda_i\mu_i$

> WTS: $2 \sum \lambda_i\mu_i \leq 1 + \sum \lambda_i ^2$

> Since $ 2 \sum \lambda_i\mu_i \leq \sum ( \lambda_i ^2 + \mu_i^2)$ and $ \sum \mu_i^2 \leq ( \sum \mu_i)^2 =1$, the result follows.

In addition, equality holds iff $ \lambda_I = \mu_I = 1$ for some $I$. (in which case, both sides are 0).